# how to modify video placement on HTML page via css?

Tags: html, css, iframe

I am beginning the HTML language, learning as a student, I try to center the iframe which contains the video, but unfortunately, I can't center that video even after writing in my CSS file:

```css
.miniature {
  width: 60%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="miniature">
  <iframe width="800" height="480" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/1w9PFlrz_Tk" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen=></iframe>
</div>
```

how can i make it work the way i wanted?

Comment: @BeerusDev do not change the code of the OP. I only didnt reject your edit because you fixed grammer. However it would have been reason to disapprove it. All the original code including errors and classes has to be maintained as such!

Answer (score -1):

`flexbox` is not needed here. The most simply soultion is: `iframe { display: block; margin: 0 auto; }`.
That way you also dont need a wrapper.

```css
iframe {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<iframe width="800" height="480" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/1w9PFlrz_Tk" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Comment: I believe you are missing the OP didn't mention he wanted the iframe to take up the entire containing div, hence his original width of 60%. If it takes up the entire div, what is the point of "centering" it.

Comment: @BeerusDev He only asked for centering an iframe which has a preset height and width in pixel. Everything else is subjective interpretation that has never been asked for. But even if he use a div with a width of 60%, the iframe would be centered within that div. YOu miss, that the iframe does not take up the entire div space (which doesnt exist in my sample) it just takes up his defined width of 800px.